# Look for specific row based on conditional formatting rules

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to look for a row that contains 6 conditional formatting rules in the column set. I set one rule for each column, each of these rules have a specific color or use the same color, and I need to find on the sheet when all the 6 colors from the 6 columns are encountered in the same row and either color that row or take me to that row.

Here's the image of the supposed row that all 6 conditional formatting rules are found within it.

[image]

Comment: formula cannot test if the cell is colored.  You will need to include the tests themselves in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another column and use `=IF( AND( logic1, logic2, ...), "TRUE", "FALSE")`, putting the logic for each other the conditional formats accordingly.

This will result in a single column spelling out for you which rows fulfill each condition. You can filter the entire table by `TRUE` and have a quick list of what you're looking for.

Comment: Sir, thank you so much for this I have been looking for this answer for so long after painfully do over 300 sheets manually of looking for matches on the rows of over 30k rows each this is god send!